# How can I returned to the same index of List View after closing the app and open it again

Tags: android

I have a long ListView that the user can scroll around before returning to the previous screen. When the user close the app and opens again, I want the list to be scrolled to the same point that it was previously. Any ideas on how to achieve this

I tried many methods ut all in vain

Answer (score 1):

```
onPause() {
   int position = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition()
   //Write position to shared preferences
}

onResume() {
  int position = //read position from shared preferences
  listView.setSelection(position)
}
```

The onPause code will get the topmost item visible (please note it may be partially visible).  The onResume code will scroll the listview to that item.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help I'm just beginner so I didn't understand what do meant when you say  //Write position to shared preferences maye something like this long text = lv.getItemIdAtPosition(position);  also is it not necessary to avoid @override

Comment: This is pseudocode, not full code.  I'm telling you what to do, you need to fill in the blanks.  Look up how to read and write shared preferences, its a common and important part of the android system for storing settings.  Also, @Override is never required, although its recomended as it can find a class of typo bugs and save time debugging.

Answer (score 1):

All credits goes to @Gabe Sechan . According to the documentation activity's lifecycle -

```
    onStart()

    onRestart()

    onResume()

    onPause()

    onStop() - Killable

    onDestroy() - Killable
```

> for those methods that are marked as being killable, after that method returns the process hosting the activity may be killed by the system at any time without another line of its code being executed. Because of this, you should use the onPause() method to write any persistent data (such as user edits) to storage .

And you got that answer from @Gabe Sechan .

I want to add a little bit with it , you may check . You asked -

> How can I returned to the same index of List View after closing the app and open it again

If the user force close/kill your app then `onPause()/onStop()/onDestroy()` would not be call . So store data in `onPause()` would be missed . So you may implement `setOnScrollListener` and `onScrollStateChanged` of your listview to check if user **stop scrolling** then store the position else not .Retrieve the saved data when activity will be created .  Example code -

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ListView listView;
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    SharedPreferences defPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    int position = defPref.getInt("position", 0);
    listView.setSelection(position);

    listView.setOnScrollListener(new ListView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            if (scrollState == 0)
                Log.i("ZI", "scroll stopped");
            //store
            ListView listView;
            listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
            int position = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();

            SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
            editor.putInt("position", position);
            editor.commit();

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

        }

    });


}
```

In this case we don't store/ retrieve data on `onPause() and onResume()` .

Comment: Thanks guys I fixed it by using Shared reference